# maximize two functions, but have the same optimal solution

Tags: calculus

I have a function, $-e^{-(x-(1/2)x^2)}$.

If I'm maximizing the function $-e^{-(x-(1/2)x^2)}$ with the respect of X, it would give me the same result (optimal solution of X) as if I was maximizing $x-(1/2)x^2.$ Why is that so?

I know that the first order derivatives of both function will be the same. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some generality: A composition of a convex function $f$ with any monotonic convex function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. An example for such a function $g$ is $exp()$.  So, if $f$ is convex, $exp(f(x))$ is convex. 
In the running example,  $f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is convex and hence $exp(f(x))$ is also convex.  Thus,optimizing $exp(f(x))$ is the same as optimizing $f(x)$.